# Why doesn't my condition (-not A -and (A -or B -or C)) work?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, logical-operators

I wrote _in function to detect if we must install packages or not. The arguments `-packages` and `+packages` work but `+base` and `+full` don't work, how can I fix it ?

```bsh
$scriptArgs=$args

function _in {
  Param($find)

  foreach ($i in $scriptArgs) {
    if ($i -eq $find) {
      return 1
    }
  }
  return 0
}

# Install packages
if (-not (_in("-packages")) -and (_in("+packages") -or _in("+base") -or _in("+full"))) {
  PrintInfo "* Installing packages"
}
```

This works:

```
PS> powershell .\scripts\win\install_zds.ps1 +packages
* Installing packages
PS> powershell .\scripts\win\install_zds.ps1 +packages -packages
```

`-packages` disables package installation and `+packages` enables package installation.

This doesn't work:

```
PS> powershell .\scripts\win\install_zds.ps1 +base
PS> powershell .\scripts\win\install_zds.ps1 +full
```

`+base` and `+full` should enable package installation.

---

**EDIT:** I would like understand why:

I follow [PetSerAI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57375172/why-my-condition-not-a-and-a-or-b-or-c-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment101234874_57375172) comment, then, I remove the parentheses like this:

```
if (-not (_in "-packages") -and ((_in "+packages") -or (_in "+base") -or (_in "+full"))) { }
```

This works, but I don't understand why. I [found this explain](https://serverfault.com/questions/819763/why-is-it-wrong-to-call-functions-with-parentheses-in-powershell) about parentheses in PowerShell:

> Powershell is a parsed and interpreted language. The interpreter see's parenthesis as a control structure and is not expected or required at the Call Site.

But with `test-function("Hello")`, `hello` is string not a structure.

```
function Test-Function {
  Param(
    [string]
    $hello
  )

  "String: $hello"
}

Test-Function("Hello")
Test-Function "Hello"
```

Comment: `if (-not (_in "-packages") -and ((_in "+packages") -or (_in "+base") -or (_in "+full")))`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks! I use a bad syntax...

Comment: Don't write your own `-in` implementation...

Comment: PowerShell interprets the bare sequence `-packages` as a parameter name and therefor doesn't pass it as an argument - qualify it with quotes: `powershell .\scripts\win\install_zds.ps1 +packages '-packages'`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 is not the same thing

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this example doesn't seem to be an issue in my script

Comment: You might have to double-escape it `"'-package'"`

Comment: `function Test-Args { Write-Host ($args -replace '^|$', '"' -join ', '); $true }; Test-Args asd fgh -and Test-Args zxc vbn; Test-Args ('asd') (('fgh')) -and Test-Args ((('zxc'))) (((('vbn')))); (Test-Args asd fgh) -and (Test-Args zxc vbn); (Test-Args ('asd') (('fgh'))) -and (Test-Args ((('zxc'))) (((('vbn')))))`

Comment: @A-312 Yes, it is the same thing.  `if ('-packages' -notin $args)` is equivalent to your own function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
-not (_in("-packages")) -and (_in("+packages") -or _in("+base") -or _in("+full"))
```

isn't evaluated in the way you apparently expect.

PowerShell functions (unlike method calls) expect their arguments as a whitespace separated list without parentheses, i.e. `_in("foo")` should be `_in "foo"`. The parentheses aren't syntactically wrong (`_in("foo")` is a valid expression), but PowerShell will parse the parentheses as a grouping expression, which is evaluated first. Meaning that PowerShell will first expand `_in("foo")` to `_in "foo"` before actually calling the function.

However, since you're putting function calls in a boolean expression you need to put grouping parentheses around each function call to have the function calls evaluated first, so that the result of the function calls is used in the boolean expression:

```
(_in "foo") -and (_in "bar")
```

Without that the boolean operators would be parsed as parameters for the first function. In other words

```
_in("foo") -and _in("bar")
```

would be expanded to

```
_in "foo" -and _in "bar"
```

which would then invoke the function `_in()` with the arguments `foo`, `-and`, `_in`, and `bar`.

Because of that your condition must be written as

```
-not (_in "-packages") -and ((_in "+packages") -or (_in "+base") -or (_in "+full"))
```

---

With that said, what you're trying to implement would not only re-implement the `-in`/`-contains` operators, it is also contrary to normal PowerShell parameter handling. I strongly recommend you look into [advanced function parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-3.0) and parameter sets. They work on both function and script level.

Example:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='none')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='base', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Base,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='full', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch]$Full
)

switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    'none' { 'install nothing' }
    'base' { 'base install' }
    'full' { 'full install' }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that Powershell is very unusual when it comes to -and and -or, *they have equal precedence*.  Most other languages aren't like this (C#, vbscript...).  It seems like it was overlooked in the beginning, and now they don't want to break existing scripts.

```bsh
$true -or $true -and $false
False

$true -or ($true -and $false)
True
```

This is more typical behavior, with + and *.  * has higher priority than +.

```
1 + 2 * 3
7

(1 + 2) * 3
9
```

Comment: I would argue that AND and OR having equal precedence is actually the *correct* behavior.